# How can I convert a bitcoin public key to a bitcoin address?

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core, public-key, php

How can I convert a bitcoin public key to a bitcoin address?

Note: I am using PHP.

Is there an existing bitcoin API or PHP-API to do that converting ?

Answer (score 8):

There is a [step-by-step tutorial](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Technical_background_of_version_1_Bitcoin_addresses#How_to_create_Bitcoin_Address) on the Bitcoin Wiki for converting Keys.

For testing there is a very good website, where you can put in a private or public key and its show you the result of any step: http://gobittest.appspot.com/Address

If you dont want to do those things on your own you could use [Bitcore](http://bitcore.io/), a JavaScript API for Bitcoin. For a pure PHP Libary there are some custom user projects on github, but I didn't tested any of them.

Comment: I can't figure out how to go from 0 to 1 in the step-by-step tutorial :( Looks like a programmatic solution might be here, but I'm thinking there must be an easier way http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/28398/how-can-i-get-the-uncompressed-public-key-from-the-compressed-public-key-in-open