# How can I get the uncompressed public key from the compressed public key in openssl?

Tags: public-key

Given a private key, I can get the uncompressed or compressed version of the public key like so.

```
EC_KEY* pKey = EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(NID_secp256k1);

std::vector<unsigned char> getPubKey(EC_KEY* pKey, bool compressed) const {
    if (compressed)
        EC_KEY_set_conv_form(pKey, POINT_CONVERSION_COMPRESSED);
    else
        EC_KEY_set_conv_form(pKey, POINT_CONVERSION_UNCOMPRESSED);

    int nSize = i2o_ECPublicKey(pKey, NULL);
    std::vector<unsigned char> pubKey(nSize, 0)
    unsigned char* pBegin = &pubKey[0];
    i2o_ECPublicKey(pKey, &pBegin)
    return pubKey;
}
```

But how can I get the uncompressed public key from the compressed public key without knowing the private key?

Comment: I answered the same question here, but with an answer in Python: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=644919.msg7205689#msg7205689 If a language-agnostic answer is suitable, I can post this as an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but I'm looking fora a canonical solution using openssl.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a compressed octet pubkey, use octet to point, then point to octet.

```
EC_POINT_oct2point(group, point, data, size, ctx);
EC_POINT_point2oct(group, point, POINT_CONVERSION_UNCOMPRESSED, data, len, ctx);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the following to get an `EC_POINT` from a compressed key:

```
int EC_POINT_set_compressed_coordinates_GFp(const EC_GROUP *group,
                                             EC_POINT *p,
                                             const BIGNUM *x, int y_bit,
                                             BN_CTX *ctx);
```

and the following to convert the `EC_POINT` to an `EC_KEY`:

```
 int EC_KEY_set_public_key(EC_KEY *key, const EC_POINT *pub);
```

From [EC_POINT_new documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/EC_POINT_new.html):

> Points can also be described in terms of their compressed
>   co-ordinates. For a point (x, y), for any given value for x such that
>   the point is on the curve there will only ever be two possible values
>   for y. Therefore a point can be set using the
>   EC_POINT_set_compressed_coordinates_GFp() and
>   EC_POINT_set_compressed_coordinates_GF2m() functions where x is the x
>   co-ordinate and y_bit is a value 0 or 1 to identify which of the two
>   possible values for y should be used.

and [EC_KEY_new documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/EC_KEY_new.html):

> The functions EC_KEY_get0_group(), EC_KEY_set_group(),
>   EC_KEY_get0_private_key(), EC_KEY_set_private_key(),
>   EC_KEY_get0_public_key(), and EC_KEY_set_public_key() get and set the
>   EC_GROUP object, the private key, and the EC_POINT public key for the
>   key respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Sample code using boringssl in c.

```
EC_KEY  eckey = EC_KEY_new();
EC_GROUP = EC_GROUP_new_by_curve_name(NID_X9_62_prime256v1);
EC_KEY_set_group(eckey, ecgrp);

EVP_PKEY pubkey = EVP_PKEY_new();
EVP_PKEY_set1_EC_KEY(pubkey, eckey);

unsigned char *ptr = raw_data->data;
o2i_ECPublicKey(&eckey, (const uint8_t **)&ptr, raw_data->len);

//pubkey is the required public key
```